# Extract Text From Word Doc Binary

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office

Microsoft has published the binary specifications for Office files.  I need to extract the text from .Doc.  This page seems to imply it is not difficult to extract the text from Doc but I don't follow.

[MS Doc Extract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615596.aspx#UnderstandMS_DOC_ExtractText)

This is what I have so far.
The values for wIdent and wFib are wrong.  Please point me in the correct direction.

```
UInt16 wIdent; // (2 bytes): An unsigned integer that specifies that this is a Word Binary File. This value MUST be 0xA5EC.
UInt16 wFib;   // (2 bytes): An unsigned integer that specifies the version number of the file format used. Superseded by FibRgCswNew.nFibNew if it is present. This value SHOULD<13> be 0x00C1.

using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{
    UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(true);

    BinaryReader brFile = new BinaryReader(fs);

    wIdent = brFile.ReadUInt16();
    Debug.WriteLine(wIdent.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:x}", wIdent));  // cfd0  wrong value
    wFib = brFile.ReadUInt16();
    Debug.WriteLine(wFib.ToString());   //  57361  wrong value

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];

    while (brFile.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(utf8.GetString(b));
    }
}
```

The above displays most of the the text but also a lot of other stuff.

I have docx working via OpenXML.  Needs more than just the iFilter as it needs semi formatted.  Run a algorithm on the text to cull out uninteresting documents.  Also used for a quick text of the document so they can decide if they want to download the file and for auto coding.

Office Interop is not an option.  This is for a server and Microsoft does not recommend Office automation in that environment.  We tried and it is not stable for the volume of documents we need to process.

Answer (score 2):

NPOI has some very limited support for reading standard Word 97-2000 DOC files.

If you are determined, you could also try to convert the code used to import Word files that is used by OpenOffice from Java into C# (if you can reasonably meet the requirements of its open-source license). The tool Sharpen can be used to help convert the code.

If you have time to pre-process the Word files before your users see them, you could use Office automation to convert the Word files into HTML, which is then a cakewalk to deal with in a server environment.

Another option would be to **not** try to invent your own reader, and instead invest in a commercial library like Aspose Words (http://www.aspose.com/). In the end, that may well be the cheapest and most sustainable option.

Comment: Thanks, converting the files is not an option as the files cannot be changed.   I will look at the other options you presented.  That msdn page made it seem easy but then again I could not even read in first offset.

Comment: On the Apose site they list ASP.NET and Win Forms but not WPF.  Do they not support WPF?  Seems strange as a file conversion is not UI.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with UI. I've used Apose in class libraries without any UI.

Comment: The more I look the more I want to make this extract work in C# and I understand I may not be able to make it work. It is fast and it contains the required text.  The app needs to extract the text from 100K+ documents in a batch then it does some proprietary analysis on that text and will cull out 90% +.  iFilter do not have enough structure for the pattern matching.  Currently we  have a front end .exe that parses out the text but it is slow and has a click charge.

Comment: NPOI.HWPF is good at extracting data from Word 97-2003. You can try it. But writing is not supported

Answer (score 1):

If this is still actual, i encountered the same problem.
The MS binary file format is common to word (.doc), excel (.xls), power point (.ppt) and all older versions. You should first follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942138.aspx) to read the FAT section of the binary, from which you will extract WordDocument stream that you can read it as you already mentioned.
Hope this helps.

Comment: To help clarify, the beginning of a word document will be the Compound header as defined link above provided by user3041596.  The value 0xcfd0 you show above is part of the Compound Header Signature.  Once you parse this header, you can then find the location of where the WordDataStream starts; which is where the FIB begins which is where you can then find the text.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, Toxy is suggested to be used. Since Toxy 1.4, both doc and docx are supported. You can check toxy.codeplex.com for details. Formatting is not supported very well in 1.4 but we will improve it in 1.6.